# DynamoDb AccessDeniedException when apparently making identical queries to table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, pynamodb

I have two API calls to the BE that are fired simultaneously. Both access the **same record** in a DynamoDb table.

90% of the time, there is no issue.

10% of the time, I get the following error:

```
pynamodb.exceptions.QueryError: Failed to query items: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) on request (KKTVJ3GL22G1053VDGJM3U4T17VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG) on table (account_entity_links) when calling the Query operation
```

This clearly does not have anything to do with permissions. My intuition tells me this has to do with the "almost" simultaneous access.

Is there any restrictions in DynamoDB with two calls accessing a record simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is clear, the role you are using does not have permission to perform a `Query` operation on table `account_entity_links`.

You state that 90% of the time the operation works, while 10% of the time it does not. My assumption here is that 90% of the time you operate on the base table, while 10% of the time you try to `Query` and index for which you are lacking permissions.

Other things to check is that pynamodb is picking up the expected role for each API you call.

Comment: It is the same line of code (i.e. the exact same DB operation) that works most of the time, and only fails even less than 10%.

Comment: I would check your Cloudtrail logs to make sure no process is deleting the policy and re-creating.

Comment: I have not worked with Cloudtrails before. What would I be looking for?

Comment: Anything I AM related

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any restrictions in DynamoDB with two calls accessing a
> record simultaneously?

No.

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html) mention

> AccessDeniedException Message: Access denied.
>
> The client did not correctly sign the request. If you are using an AWS
> SDK, requests are signed for you automatically; otherwise, go to the
> Signature version 4 signing process in the AWS General Reference.

I don't know anything about pynamnodb, but you might check to see if there's a newer version than what you're currently using.